# Jumpseat Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

We are facing the issue with jumpseat installation in ubuntu 16.04.

Error:The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

We have installed the mongodb and followed this link.

but no use its remain same.

help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue solved with the php version 5.6. and the install the mongo db

Please follow the below links:
http://wiki.jumpseat.io/index.php?title=Ubuntu_16.04_Installation
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/

Thanks